# Undefined function 'fitrsvm' for input arguments of type 'double'

Tags: matlab, svm

I am using Matalb 2014 . on using which function it shows :

```
which fitrsvm
'fitrsvm' not found.
```

fitrsvm is an inbuilt function so why matlab doesn't recognize it?
I want to use svm in regression is there any other way to do it ?

On tying "ver" it shows

```
MATLAB Version: 8.4.0.150421 (R2014b)
MATLAB License Number: unknown
Operating System: Microsoft Windows 8.1 Pro Version 6.3 (Build 9600)
Java Version: Java 1.7.0_11-b21 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MATLAB                                                Version 8.4        (R2014b)
Simulink                                              Version 8.4        (R2014b)
Bioinformatics Toolbox                                Version 4.5        (R2014b)
Communications System Toolbox                         Version 5.7        (R2014b)
Computer Vision System Toolbox                        Version 6.1        (R2014b)
Control System Toolbox                                Version 9.8        (R2014b)
Curve Fitting Toolbox                                 Version 3.5        (R2014b)
DSP System Toolbox                                    Version 8.7        (R2014b)
Data Acquisition Toolbox                              Version 3.6        (R2014b)
Database Toolbox                                      Version 5.2        (R2014b)
Econometrics Toolbox                                  Version 3.1        (R2014b)
Financial Toolbox                                     Version 5.4        (R2014b)
Fixed-Point Designer                                  Version 4.3        (R2014b)
Fuzzy Logic Toolbox                                   Version 2.2.20     (R2014b)
Global Optimization Toolbox                           Version 3.3        (R2014b)
Image Acquisition Toolbox                             Version 4.8        (R2014b)
Image Processing Toolbox                              Version 9.1        (R2014b)
Instrument Control Toolbox                            Version 3.6        (R2014b)
MATLAB Builder EX                                     Version 2.5.1      (R2014b)
MATLAB Builder JA                                     Version 2.3.2      (R2014b)
MATLAB Builder NE                                     Version 4.2.2      (R2014b)
MATLAB Coder                                          Version 2.7        (R2014b)
MATLAB Compiler                                       Version 5.2        (R2014b)
MATLAB Report Generator                               Version 4.0        (R2014b)
Mapping Toolbox                                       Version 4.0.2      (R2014b)
Neural Network Toolbox                                Version 8.2.1      (R2014b)
Optimization Toolbox                                  Version 7.1        (R2014b)
Parallel Computing Toolbox                            Version 6.5        (R2014b)
Partial Differential Equation Toolbox                 Version 1.5        (R2014b)
Real-Time Windows Target                              Version 4.5        (R2014b)
Robust Control Toolbox                                Version 5.2        (R2014b)
Signal Processing Toolbox                             Version 6.22       (R2014b)
SimBiology                                            Version 5.1        (R2014b)
SimHydraulics                                         Version 1.15       (R2014b)
SimMechanics                                          Version 4.5        (R2014b)
SimPowerSystems                                       Version 6.2        (R2014b)
Simscape                                              Version 3.12       (R2014b)
Simulink Coder                                        Version 8.7        (R2014b)
Simulink Control Design                               Version 4.1        (R2014b)
Simulink Real-Time                                    Version 6.1        (R2014b)
Spreadsheet Link EX                                   Version 3.2.2      (R2014b)
Stateflow                                             Version 8.4        (R2014b)
Statistics Toolbox                                    Version 9.1        (R2014b)
Symbolic Math Toolbox                                 Version 6.1        (R2014b)
System Identification Toolbox                         Version 9.1        (R2014b)
Wavelet Toolbox                                       Version 4.14       (R2014b)
```

There is statistics toolbox but no statistics and machine learning toolbox.

Comment: The [documentation](http://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitrsvm.html) says, it was only introduced in Matlab 2015b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is part of Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox. 
Maybe you don't have the toolbox. 
type "ver" in the command line to see what toolboxes you have.

Comment: Thank you , but there is no such toolbox , i have edited the question ,is there any way to add it

Comment: I  see now that it was introduced in 2015b.

Answer (score 1):

fitrsvm is working in matlab 2016